# Ignore case when searching an Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to ignore case when doing a search what's the best way to do it? (No Jquery please)

```
function search(searchValue) {
    var found = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < photoData.length; i++) {
        if (photoData[i].description.search(searchValue) != -1) {
            found.push(photoData[i]);
        }
}
console.log(found);
return found;
}
```

I tried doing `search(searchValue.ignoreCase)` but it returns duplicates of any that have an uppercase letter. So any suggestions? I want to ignore the case of photoData's description

Comment: Well, you can create a regex object and make it a case-insensitive search: `if (photoData[i].description.search(new RegExp(searchValue, "i")) != -1) {`

Comment: That worked really well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `new RegExp` and use the case-insensitive flag, like:

```
function search(array, searchValue) {
    var matchedValues, re, i, j, cur;

    matchedValues = [];
    re = new RegExp(searchValue, "i");
    for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = array[i];
        if (cur.description.search(re) !== -1) {
            matchedValues.push(cur);
        }
    }
    return matchedValues;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7veds/

Although you can use the `Array.filter` method also:

```
function search(array, searchValue) {
    var re = new RegExp(searchValue, "i");
    return array.filter(function (item, idx) {
        return item.description.search(re) !== -1;
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/TKphp/

Reference:

- `Array.filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- `RegExp`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters

Comment: I just used your code from the comment and it works just fine! Thanks mate.

Comment: Maybe move new RegExp out of the loop?

Comment: @dc5 Yeah, crap, good point. I do it in my second example, not sure why I didn't in my first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not dealing with Unicode characters (as some case conversions work unexpectedly in some Unicode supported languages), do this:

```
if (photoData[i].description.toUpperCase() === searchValue.toUpperCase()) {
    your code
}
```

or you could use toLowerCase...

Comment: Like this better than the reg ex approach (more readable), and also +1 for pointing out the potential issues with Unicode.

Comment: @GoloRoden You like a solution that doesn't work as intended? `.toUppercase() === .toUpperCase()` does **not** do the same thing as `.search()`

Comment: @GoloRoden No big deal. The first thing I thought of was to do this as well. But then I realized what `.search()` was doing and knew this approach couldn't be used to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

here is a small snippet from [Case insensitive search in array](http://www.codeplussoft.com/Snippets/javascript-search-inarray)

```
function SearchArray( element, array ) {
var len = array.length, str = element.toString().toLowerCase();
for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    if ( array[i].toLowerCase() == str ) { return i; }
}
return -1;
```

}